# What is document use for in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, document

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and I want to understand this statement:

```
document.slider.src=img[number].src;
```

Also I need to know what `document` use for.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document  It refers to the currently loaded document as an object.  All the elements on the page are descendants of `document`.

Comment: have you searched the web for tutorials/samples?

Comment: In your particular statement, `slider` is some object that lives insides the current document (a widget of some sort, I suppose) and its `src` attribute is being set to the current `src` of the `img` array at `[number]`

Comment: As Michael said, document is the parent of all elements, means every element in your website is inside the document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [global object "document"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html) represents the HTML document which is displayed in the current browser window.

document.slider refers to the HTML tag with the property `id="slider"`. Note that this way of referring to document nodes is deprecated because of potential naming conflicts with the other properties and functions of the document object. A much better way is to use `document.getElementById("slider")`.

`.src` accesses the src property of that HTML tag (when it's an image, it's the URL to the image file).

`img` seems to be an array of images which was created or retrieved earlier. Presumably with a call to `document.images()` which returns an array with all `<img>` HTML tags on the page.  `img[number]` refers to an element of that array. `number` is a variable which most likely contains a number. It says which element of the array is accessed. When number=3, for example, the 4th element of the array is accessed, because arrays start counting with 0. The property `.src`  of that image node is then retrieved and assigned to the `.src` of the slider.

Answer (score 5):

`document` is an object. The line of code you pasted is supposed to run in the web browser. The web browser will have JavaScript engine. That engine will provide the developer with some runtime objects, such as `document` and `window` to interact with. The environment is called Browser Object Model (or BOM). You can read more about it [on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document).